# Ngshow/hide based on ajax return value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Does anyone know of a way to dynamically use ngshow to show/hide content based on an ajax return value?

This is what I have so far:

```
$scope.loggedShow = false;

var user = '';

$scope.login = function(username, password) {

  $http({
    url: 'ajax/login.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      'username': username,
      'password': password
    }

  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    console.log(data);
    console.log('working');

    user = 'logged';


    if (user == 'logged') {

      $scope.loggedShow = true;

    } else {

      $scope.loggedShow = false;

    }

    getBanners();

  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('womp womp');
  });


};
```

And here's the html:

```
<div class="widget-header header-color-blue"  ng-show="loggedShow" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h4 class="bigger lighter">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i>&nbsp;
                BANNERS
            </h4>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button restrict access="admin" ng-click="addNewClicked=!addNewClicked;" 
                    class="btn btn-sm btn-danger header-elements-margin">
                <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;
                NEW PROJECT
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" ng-model="filterBanners" 
                   class="form-control search header-elements-margin" 
                   placeholder="FILTER BANNERS">
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Basically, I set the value in the controller to false, then when the return value comes in, I validate it and set it to true, which should show the element.  Unfortunately, this isn't working as intended.  It processes the original statements fine (it properly hides the element), but on return of the value the scope doesn't update.  Is this how angular works?  Should I be using a directive instead?

Comment: Is data a literal string? You should check it.

Comment: It's correctly processing the loop, I can console log inside of the check.  user == 'logged' is valid and it is a string.  You can see from the code I'm actually just setting it manually to check to see if I can even get this to work.

Comment: Looks like this View is outside the scope of the controller. Then loggedShow is undefined everytime, what's interpreted for  ng-show as false everytime. Take a look if this View is inside the ng-controller scope where you set the variable.

Comment: have you tried $apply to trigger a digest after the http call comes back, your view might simply not being updated even though the value changes.

Comment: If loggedShow doesn't work, tell us do you see or not see your div?

Comment: Okay, this is going to sound really stupid (because it is), but I had the controller declared on my index.html, but also on one of my partials.  Once I had once controller over both partials it worked.  Sorry for the stupidity.  Obviously angular is not going to be okay with multiple declarations of a controller.